# Is it possible to implement a class with a parameter of type <Generic extends X>?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, subclass

I'm trying to create a new class that looks like this:

```
public class WikiGraph<V extends Node> implements DirectedGraph<V extends Node>
```

It seems that this is illegal, and when I extend the graph and try to use a parameter that is a subclass of Node, this is a problem. I'm trying to create a subclass that looks like this:

```
 public class WikiGraphWeighted<WeightedNode> implements DirectedGraph<WeightedNode>
```

Are there any workarounds for this. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Just do `WikiGraph<V extends Node> implements DirectedGraph<V>`. The second `<V>` will use all the constraints that the first one establishes.

Comment: Thanks @yshavit, that seems to be the solution!

Comment: Note that the `<V extends Node>` at the `WikiGraph` *declares* the type parameter whereas the `implements DirectedGraph<V>` clause *uses* the type parameter to describe the parameterization of the super class. This can be even less intuitive when looking at the declaration [`class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) where `<E extends Enum<E>>` at the `class Enum` *declares* the type parameter while the inner `<E>` at the `… extends Enum<E>` *uses* the type parameter, within its own declaration. Only the declaration has constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint on V remains in force when it's used elsewhere in scope.

```
public class WikiGraph< V extends Node > implements DirectedGraph< V > {

}
```